# C# String.Format on stream reader

Tags: c#

I have this html file that I am reading into memory, then I want to replace the **{0}** with a **firstName** so I am tring to use `String.Format()` but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code so far:

```
    private async Task SendRegistrationEmail(EmailService emailService, User model)
    {

        // Get our path
        var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/assets/emails/registered/index.html");

        // Read our email template
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {

            // Read our html
            var html = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var body = String.Format(html, model.FirstName);

            // Send our email
            await emailService.SendAsync(model.Email, "Kudos Sports - Registration Complete", body);
        }
    }
```

The line with `String.Format(html, model.Firstname)` is returning an error stating:

> Input string was not in a correct format

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Without seeing what html is, no

Comment: Show the html please we can't help you otherwise

Comment: I think you has problem with `{0}` in HTML

Comment: You probably have other `{` or `}` in the HTML - eg: http://rextester.com/OYVSRF20810

Comment: This seems like something that would be a lot easier to solve using an MVC framework for ASP like Razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html input line contained characters that are not allowed as `String.Format()` arguments or you have another `{` or `}` in your input. For example, if input string will have something like "Name={0} value={1}" and you use `String.Format()` passing only 1 value - you will get an exception.

One of solutions to use something more unique as replacement template, for example %%FirstName%% and use String.Replace instead.

```
var replaced = html.Replace("%%FirstName%%", firstName);
```

Comment: That gives a different exception: http://rextester.com/TVSD30630 `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.`

Comment: You are right. If input string is like this "something{"  you will get exception like originally mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `html` does not contain a placeholder like `{0}` for the second argument or placecolders like `{1}` for which no data is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure the html doesn't contain any other `{` or `}` braces like for example some javascript within it. If it does, you have to escape them before using `String.Format`